# How to run local notification using revmob

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, notifications, revmob

Revmob is working fine in my app,but i want to send local notification using revmob

[[RevMobAds session] scheduleLocalNotification];

// in your AppDelegate.m

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [[RevMobAds session] processLocalNotification:notification];
  }

This is the code i am using,but after that it is not running,there is something wrong with my code,i guess,please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [RevMob site](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios-api/Classes/RevMobAds.html#//api/name/scheduleLocalNotification), the scheduleLocalNotification method scheduled a notifications at a time which RevMob expects to be the best. Yesterday this time was around 5:30pm (local time), but they can change it if they think is necessary.

If you want to test the local notification in a specific time you can use the [scheduleLocalNotification:](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios-api/Classes/RevMobAds.html#//api/name/scheduleLocalNotification%3a) method.